# how can I show the name of the user for something he created in my website?

Tags: python, django

I'm designing a website using djagno with a Q&A section. in this section there is a part that users can see all of questions and also can see who asked any question. I did something but it just shows the username who is logged in for all questions!!!
any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.
This is my view:

```
    def getUserInfo(userID):
    row = msignup.objects.get(id=userID)
    fname = row.fname
    lname = row.lname
    mobile = row.mobile
    email = row.email

    userInfo = {
        'userID': userID,
        'fname': fname,
        'lname': lname,
        'degree': degree,
        'field':  field,
        'mobile': mobile,
        'email': email,
    }
    return userInfo




def my_question(request):
    userID = request.session.get('mainSession', 0)
    userInfo = getUserInfo(userID)
    user = msignup.objects.get(id=userID)
    q = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'myquestions' : q, 'userInfo':userInfo}
    return render (request,'questions/myquestions.html',context)
```

#################And This is My Model:

```
  class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(msignup, related_name = "uquestion")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    favorites = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    has_accepted_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Question'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'
        ordering = ('-update_date',)
```

Comment: post your model

Comment: I did it. thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 'my_question' you are using **userID = request.session.get('mainSession', 0)** which will always return current user.

you must use **models.ForeignKey(User)** in question model and save user id while creating questions.

Note : request.session.get('mainSession', 0) will always return current user.

Comment: I did use the models.ForeignKey in my models. how can I save user ID while creating a question and attach it to that question?? I added my model by the way.

Comment: well , whenever your is creating a question and if he is logged in on your site then simply use "request.user" to get his user id and save in the question object.

Answer (score 1):

In the templates to show the details of the question(like author, published date, etc..) use

```
{% for question in myquestions %}
     {{question.user}}  # use .fnamn or .lname to show first or last name of the user and so on
     {{question.create_date}}
     .......
{% endfor %}
```

and for the details of the logged in user, you can use 'userInfo'.